# Can Item Frames be nested?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Can you place an [Item Frame](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Item_frame) within an Item Frame?  How about an item, inside an item frame, inside an item frame?  If you can do this, is there a limit?

Comment: Talk about frameception

Comment: Haha @JeffreyLin check the original post title before it got edited

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An item frame is an item, so you can put it in an item frame. However, an item may only be placed in a frame by right-clicking a wall-mounted frame with it, so frames in your inventory are always empty. Thus, you can only place an empty item frame into an item frame.